# CSS z-index for Shadow only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to overlap my shadow created during hover transitions of my round button with a div (red one), so that the pusle effect doesn't show on my div but at other places.
Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: #292f33;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.btntest {
  width: 190px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 299;
  position: fixed;
}
.button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.button:hover {
  animation: pulse 1.1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(85, 172, 238, .4);
  }
  49.9% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  75% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(85, 172, 238, .6);
  }
  99.9% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  25% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(85, 172, 238, .4);
  }
  49.9% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  50% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  75% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(85, 172, 238, .6);
  }
  99.9% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 298;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Pulse Effect</p>
<a class="button"></a>
<div class="btntest">Test</div>
```

I Have given z-index property for the transition shadows but everytime I hover, the button also hides back below the div - and I only want shadow to hide.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @connexo said, the shadow of an element is always on the same `z-index` level of its element.
A possible workaround is to create an other *hidden* element, which will stand on a lower layer, animated while hovering you real button :

```css
body {
  background: #292f33;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.btntest {
  width: 190px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  z-index: 299;
  position: fixed;
}
.button {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 300;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.fake-btn {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 298;
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.button:hover + .fake-btn {
  animation: pulse 1.1s ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(85, 172, 238, .4);
  }
  49.9% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(85, 172, 238, .6);
  }
  99.9% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(85, 172, 238, .4);
  }
  49.9% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  50% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  75% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(85, 172, 238, .6);
  }
  99.9% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(85, 172, 238, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Pulse Effect</p>

<a class="button"></a>
<p class="fake-btn"></p>
<div class="btntest">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make it work this way. The shadow of an element will always be stacked on the same z-index level as the element that has the shadow.

Comment: I don't see one as of now. An element is either in front of another one, or behind it.